# Send PUSH Notification to Android Client from java class on app-Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, push-notification

I have the requirement to send a PUSH notification to an android client from my java class. The class has been written using the guidelines provided at the url : http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html (Section 2.4 - Send Messages) This works fine on the standard application servers like JBOSS and Weblogic.

But the application needs to be moved to google app-engine but the class throws a compilation error saying : 'The class javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier is not supported by GAE's Java runtime environment'. Similar error is thrown for 'SSLSession' class too.

Is there a way this can be overcome ? Or is there is any other way to send PUSH notifications from Java classes running on the app-engine ?

Thanks,
Vinay

Answer (score 1):

It can't be overcome directly, meaning you can't make those classes run on GAE. As for a solution, I'm not sure why you would want to use a custom HostnameVerifier, so just try without it: use `HttpURLConnection` instead of `HttpsURLConnection` and remove all the "hostnameVerifier" parts.

Edit: you can also use App Engine's [fetch API](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/URLFetchService.html), that is supported for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Viruzzo...I changed it to HttpURLConnection and removed the private class extending HostNameVerifier, but get a new error at runtime saying

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.net.SocketFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.

when the method is executed. Might be because sockets are not supported fully by GAE ?

Do you know if there is any other way to achieve PUSH from Java on GAE?

Comment: Where does it throw it? There is no explicit reference to it in the code you linked. You only need to do a simple POST to the C2DM server to do push, so it should work perfectly fine with `HttpURLConnection` on GAE.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question `Is there is any other way to send PUSH notifications from Java classes running on the app-engine?`, the answer is yes, third party services such as [Beaconpush](http://beaconpush.com/) or [Spire.io](http://www.spire.io) could be integrated well with app engine, and in some cases could be much cheaper in terms of cost compared to using the App Engine Channel API.

Comment: Hi Ibrahim,  Can you confirm if they can be plugged into Java classes ? The requirement is to send PUSH notifications from Java classses which are running on App-Engine.

Comment: He is already using Google's [C2DM](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/android/c2dm/), that is exactly the same service as those two; he is having problem accessing the service, he doesn't want to (and shouldn't) implement a push service.

Comment: @Viruzzo: I answered his valid question and give him valid alternatives for his considerations, why the need for downvotes? Vinay: You could use their REST API to push messages via URLFetch API, that's what I did on my app.